# Angular Node JS with Spring Boot Web services

Tags: node.js, angular, spring-boot

I have couple of web services and I need to create the UI with Angular 4 for those web services under the same Spring Boot project which running on Apache Tomcat.

However I have created the UI separately using NPM and node js server, will it be wise to integrate the Angular pages in my spring boot project and call the internal web services or keep it on a different server and call the services using HTTP calls and keep Node Js server for Angular?

Comment: Tomcat is perfectly able to serve static files. I could imagine using a reverse proxy like nginx or apache (for SSL, load balancing or whatever) that would serve the static files directly, but I don't see why you would use a NodeJS server to serve static files.